# Changing sign of elements of a list on even positions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists of equal sizes (odd or even), e.g.

```
list={{1,-2,3,1,3,4},{3,5,6,-1,9,0},{1,-2,-4,-5,1,5},{1,-1,2,3,5,4},...}
```

I would like to change signs of every element which is on even or odd position. In the example above, for the choice of change on even positions, it should give the following result:

```
 listnew={{1,2,3,-1,3,-4},{3,-5,6,1,9,0},{1,2,-4,5,1,-5},{1,1,2,-3,5,-4},...}
```

What is the most effective way to achieve this? (The length of `list` may be huge here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) can not only extract positions of elements (in [`Slot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) 2, always), but also further apply transformations to the elements themselves (`Slot` 1). So in my opinion, it is the most suitable one to do the job desired:

```
MapIndexed[(-1)^(#2[[2]] + 1) # &, list, {2}]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
list = {{1, -2, 3, 1, 3, 4}, {3, 5, 6, -1, 9, 0}, {1, -2, -4, -5, 1, 
    5}, {1, -1, 2, 3, 5, 4}};
v = {1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1};
Times[v, #] & /@ list
Outer[Times, {v}, list, 1] // First
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to multiply even positions by -1:

```
listeven = list =
  {{1, -2, 3, 1, 3, 4}, {3, 5, 6, -1, 9, 0}, 
   {1, -2, -4, -5, 1, 5}, {1, -1, 2, 3, 5, 4}};
listeven[[All, 2 ;; ;; 2]] *= -1;
listeven
(* {{1, 2, 3, -1, 3, -4}, {3, -5, 6, 1, 9, 0},
    {1, 2, -4, 5, 1, -5}, {1, 1, 2, -3, 5, -4}} *)
```

A small change multiplies the odd positions:

```
listodd = list =
  {{1, -2, 3, 1, 3, 4}, {3, 5, 6, -1, 9, 0},
   {1, -2, -4, -5, 1, 5}, {1, -1, 2, 3, 5, 4}};
listodd[[All, 1 ;; ;; 2]] *= -1;
listodd
(* {{-1, -2, -3, 1, -3, 4}, {-3, 5, -6, -1, -9, 0},
    {-1, -2, 4, -5, -1, 5}, {-1, -1, -2, 3, -5, 4}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is one way:

```
MapIndexed[{n, pos} |-> If[ EvenQ @ Last @ pos, -n, n], list, {2}]
```

Answer (score 6):

This should be reasonably fast, I think:

```
list.DiagonalMatrix[{1,-1,1,-1,1,-1}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, -1, 3, -4}, {3, -5, 6, 1, 9, 0}, {1, 2, -4, 5, 1, -5}, {1, 1, 2, -3, 5, -4}}

```
list.DiagonalMatrix[{1,-1,1,-1,1,-1}]==listnew
```

> True

Alternatively:

```
With[{x=Length@list[[1]]}, list.SparseArray[Band[{1, 1},{x,x}] -> {1,-1}]]==listnew
```

> True

where

```
list={{1,-2,3,1,3,4},{3,5,6,-1,9,0},{1,-2,-4,-5,1,5},{1,-1,2,3,5,4}}
```